# Read ble values and update livedata/recyclerview list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-livedata

I have an Android application, that reads Bluetooth values from a device. I present these values in a recyclerView. I would like to find a way to update this list and i feel abit lost since i tried diffrent solutions that i found on google.

I really dont know if it's my recyclerView thats the issue or my livedata Observer that is not getting triggerd. When i try to read the values again the list disappears, but i can see in my logs that there is a new list of values comming from the viewmodel

The app runs as i intended the first iteration.

I can provide more code if needed

Sharing some code for extra clarity

Here i read the values where i retrive a byteArray.

```
ReadLineNodeValues().iRObjectTemperature -> {
                        bleListViewModel.addBleToList(characteristic.value)
}
```

Which i send to my ViewModel here

```
class BleValueViewModel: ViewModel() {

    fun addBleToList(bleValue: ByteArray) {
            blueToothLEvalue.add(bleValue)
            mutableLiveDataBluetooth.postValue(blueToothLEvalue)
    }

    fun getList(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ByteArray>> {
        return mutableLiveDataBluetooth
    }
```

Here i trying to retrive the list where i add it to my recyclverView

```
 private fun showItems() {
        val bleValueViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(BleValueViewModel::class.java)
        bleValueViewModel.getList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            if (it.size == 26) {
                showlist(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

RecyclerView

```
class LineNodeValueDataAdapter :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<LineNodeBigViewHolder>() {

    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<LinenNodeValueData>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItem: LinenNodeValueData,
            newItem: LinenNodeValueData
        ): Boolean {
            return oldItem.valueOne == newItem.valueOne && oldItem.valueTwo == newItem.valueTwo && oldItem.valueThree == newItem.valueThree && oldItem.valueFour == newItem.valueFour
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: LinenNodeValueData,
            newItem: LinenNodeValueData
        ): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

     val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LineNodeBigViewHolder {

        val binding = CardviewListlayoutValueBinding
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return LineNodeBigViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LineNodeBigViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val place = differ.currentList[position]
        holder.bind(place)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = differ.currentList.size


}
```

I convert the values since they all come as ByteArrays

```
   fun showlist(listValues: MutableList<ByteArray>) {

        //Systemnode
        val systemNodeMCUTemp = String(listValues[0])
        val systemNodeVoltages = String(listValues[1])
        val systemNodeWeatherSensor = String(listValues[2])
        val systemNodeOpenThreadCfg = String(listValues[3])
        //Linenode
        val currentLineNode = String(listValues[4])

        val acceleroMeterX = ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[5]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        val acceleroMeterY = ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[6]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        val acceleroMeterZ = ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[7]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        val iRObjectTemperature =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[8]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        val contactSensorTemperature =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[9]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        val magneticField = ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[10]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        val internalVoltage1V8 =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[11]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        val internalVoltagevBusRail =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[12]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        val internalVoltageVDD =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[13]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        val internalVoltageVDDH =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[14]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        
        val powerHarvestingVoltageSol1 =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[15]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        val powerHarvestingVoltageSol2 =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[16]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float

        val powerHarvestingVoltageEmppt =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[17]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float
        val powerHarvestingVoltageHmppt =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[18]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float

        val eHFieldHField =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[19]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float

        val eHFieldEField =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[20]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float

        val ambientTemperaturesAcc =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[21]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float

        val ambientTemperaturesIR =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[22]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float

        val ambientTemperaturesMag =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[23]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float

        val ambientTemperaturesMCU =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[24]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float

        val openThreadCFG =
            ByteBuffer.wrap(listValues[25]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).float

        val systemNodeList = ArrayList<SystemValue>()
        systemNodeList.add(SystemValue("Systemode MguTemp", systemNodeMCUTemp))
        systemNodeList.add(SystemValue("Systemnode Voltages", systemNodeVoltages))
        systemNodeList.add(SystemValue("Systemnode WeatherSensor", systemNodeWeatherSensor))
        systemNodeList.add(SystemValue("Systemnode OpenThreadCfg", systemNodeOpenThreadCfg))

        val lineNodevaluelist = ArrayList<LinenNodeValueData>()

        val lineNodeListBle = ArrayList<SystemValue>()
        lineNodeListBle.add(SystemValue("LineNode Service", currentLineNode))
        lineNodeListBle.add(SystemValue("Current LineNode", acceleroMeterX.toString()))
        //lineNodeListBle.add(SystemValue("Acclero meter", lineNodeValueSeven.toString()))
        Timber.i("Acclerometer2 :: ${acceleroMeterY}}")

        lineNodeListBle.add(
            SystemValue(
                "Accelero Meter",
                "X: $acceleroMeterX " + "Y:  $acceleroMeterY"
                        + " Z: $acceleroMeterZ"
            )
        )

        lineNodeListBle.add(
            SystemValue(
                "iRObject Temperature",
                iRObjectTemperature.toString()
            )
        )
        lineNodeListBle.add(
            SystemValue(
                "ContactSensor Temperature",
                contactSensorTemperature.toString()
            )
        )
        lineNodeListBle.add(SystemValue("Magnetic Field", magneticField.toString()))
        lineNodevaluelist.add(
            LinenNodeValueData(
                "Internal Voltage",
                "1V8: $internalVoltage1V8",
                "Vbus rail: $internalVoltagevBusRail",
                "VDD: $internalVoltageVDD",
                "VDDH: $internalVoltageVDDH"
            )
        )
        lineNodevaluelist.add(
            LinenNodeValueData(
                "Power Harvesting Voltage",
                "Sol1: $powerHarvestingVoltageSol1",
                "Sol2: $powerHarvestingVoltageSol2",
                "E-Mppt: $powerHarvestingVoltageEmppt", "H-Mppt: $powerHarvestingVoltageHmppt"
            )
        )
        lineNodeListBle.add(
            SystemValue(
                "eHField",
                "H-field: $eHFieldHField E-field: $eHFieldEField"
            )
        )
        lineNodevaluelist.add(
            LinenNodeValueData(
                "Ambient Temperatures",
                "Acc: $ambientTemperaturesAcc",
                "IR: $ambientTemperaturesIR",
                "Mag: $ambientTemperaturesMag",
                "Mcu: $ambientTemperaturesMCU"
            )
        )
        lineNodeListBle.add(SystemValue("openThreadCFG", openThreadCFG.toString()))

        setupRecyclerViewSystemNode(binding.systemNodeRecyclerView, systemNodeList)
        Timber.i("blueviewRecycler :: ${systemNodeList.size}")
        setupRecylerViewLineNodeOne(binding.lineNodeRecyclerView, lineNodeListBle, lineNodevaluelist)
        Timber.i("blueviewRecycler1 :: ${lineNodeListBle.size}+${lineNodevaluelist.size}")
    }
```

Have a nice day everyone
Kind regards
Droid

Comment: You can always pass in your live data object to the recyclerview.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @KristyWelsh i will look into that

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a condition.

```
  if (it.size == 26) {
                showlist(it)
            }
```

If you add new values to the list, list.size changed and condition is false. So, just remove a condition:

```
bleValueViewModel.getList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                showlist(it)
        }
```

also, i hope you call `showItems` only once.

Regarding your diff utils implementation, from the doc:

```
areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition)
```

> Called by the DiffUtil when it wants to check whether two items have
> the same data.

```
areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition)
```

> Called by the DiffUtil to decide whether two object represent the same
> Item.

Also it looks like you should reimplement your DIfUtils Callback:

```
private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<LinenNodeValueData>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItem: LinenNodeValueData,
            newItem: LinenNodeValueData
        ): Boolean {
            return //return true if i's the same item. I suppose in your case you should check that it's the same ble characteristic.
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: LinenNodeValueData,
            newItem: LinenNodeValueData
        ): Boolean {
            return // return true if it has the same content. If you return true it means that content(values) for the object has not change. In other case if values are different, you should return false, it means that values for characteristic changed and recyclerView should update respective view.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AnatoliiChub, Yea i removed that condition now. But i have noticed something else. It seems that my list just appends new items to the list in my viewmodel and doesnt update the current values that is in the list. Its there a way to just replace these old readvalues with new readvalues?

Comment: Ok, I can't find a place where do you set list of objects to the adapter. But please check that the list of items that you setting to the adapter, contains only new items.

Comment: Sure i have edited the post, So what im trying todo in showlist is to convert every ByteArray object into a the string/float.@AnatoliiChub

Comment: So as I can understand, you receiving a new values for ble characteristics. And you need to show only last value for each characteristic, right?

Comment: Yes, the lasted value in each characteristic

Comment: Looks like you have an issue in your implementation of Diffutil differ. I've updated the answer. Check the answer, I described how to implement callbacks(check comments inside the callback's methods in my answer)

Comment: I thank you for your time i really appreciate it. But i noticed  the list in viewModel is increasing in size everytime i try to update the list. i dont know if the differutil understands.  if its new values since i think im only sending in same 26 values all the time